# Allow users to create rooms, but prevent them to change the room configuration

Tags: xmpp, ejabberd

How can I configure ejabberd so the users can create rooms, but can't change the default configuration?

I have look into the ejabberd guide (2.1.13) without luck, also tried to google it. So maybe there is something I'm not understanding right or this can't be done with ejabberd. Any ejabberd master that can help me out?

I know I can prevent the users to change the persistent config, but I'm interested in prevent them to change the public option.